# Splitting a RASTER data (a DEM) using Quadtree or R* tree

Tags: raster, splitting, rtree

I want to create a tree of raster images, of which `root` node would be the largest which is `original\input` raster. The child nodes of root node would be the resultant rasters produced after splitting using splitRaster().

The below code splits original raster into 4 children rasters. The problem is I am not able to save these children rasters as nodes of a tree(`a quadtree\ R*`).

Below is the Rscript which successfully splits raster recursively.

```
  require(raster)
  require(rgdal)
  require(foreach)
  require(SpaDES)

  b <- raster(file.choose(), package = "raster")
  ra <- b[[1]] # use first layer only
  parent<-0
  xlist<-c()
  splita<- function (r,level,parent){
    tmpdir <- file.path(tempdir(), paste("splitRaster-AtLevel",level))
    strt<-Sys.time() 
    nx <-2
    ny <-2  
    outpath <- paste("D:/project/outputrasters/AtLevel",level)
    dir.create(outpath)

    # parallel cropping
    if (interactive()) {
      n <- pmin(parallel::detectCores(), 4) # use up to 4 cores
      beginCluster(n)
      y3 <- splitRaster(r, nx, ny, c(0.5, 0.5), path = file.path(outpath, paste("Level",level)))
      files <- list.files(path=tmpdir,pattern = "rasterlayer_tile.*.gri$")
      outfiles <- paste0(outpath, files)
      extension(outfiles) <- 'tif'
      iters=4
      print (paste("splitting raster into 4 regions at level ",level ))

      for(i in 1:iters){
        print(paste("max elevation of region ",i,"is",maxValue(y3[[i]])))
        rc <- writeRaster(y3[[i]],file = paste0(outpath, paste("rasterlayer_tile", i, sep = ".")),bylayer =TRUE ,format="GTiff",overwrite= TRUE)
      }
      endCluster()
    }
    print((level)  
    if (parent<4) {    
      iters<-4
      for(i in 1:iters){         
        splita(y3[[i]],level,parent)      
        parent<-parent + 1
      }
    }
  }
  splita(ra,1)
  unlink(tmpdir, recursive = TRUE)

  print(Sys.time()-strt)
```

[image: console shows that input raster is split into 4 regions and the maximum elevation is printed for 4 corresponding region]

Comment: Please **edit** the question to describe the problem you are encountering (Error messages, etc). GIS SE uses a "Focused question/Best answer" model; this format is not compatible with generic code review services. Please take the  [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how we operate.

Comment: Question has been edited @AndreSilva ..Thank You ..

Comment: Any suggestion or hints  would be helpful :)

Comment: It remains unclear as to how this is a GIS question. You state that the code works, though *splitting* a raster with a quadtree makes little sense. I'm not an R person, but your self-identified task seems to violate most of the intended uses for the  data structures involved, which makes me think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that you should be asking about the *problem* you face, not about the flawed *implementation*.

Comment: ohhh i see,sorry  thats my mistake of laying the question improperly. i have half implemented (spliiting task). i needed help for remaining part (creating quadtree )

Comment: i'm trying to keep a Quadtree by splitting nodes.@Vince